# Method does not override any method from it's superclass in Swift3?

Tags: swift

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
     var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
for attributes  in cache {
  if attributes.frame.intersects(rect ) {
    layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
  }
}
return layoutAttributes }
```

Here I'm getting the error.

> Method does not override any method from it's superclass.

How can I resolve the issue.

Any one can you please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is more about Apple's frameworks than about Swift: which class are you inheriting from? Is this on iOS, macOS...? Maybe there's no such method to override in the superclass, or maybe the method changed its name/signature. Either way, looking at the documentation for the superclass will give the solution (removing override will just create a useless method that nothing will call).

Comment: Are you sure, that you try to do this inside instance of layoutAttributesClass?

Answer (score 1):

If you are really trying to override that method in its right place, Try removing the method name and type `override func layoutAttributes` and select the correct override from auto complete. These kind of problems sometimes occur because of Swift's syntax changes in different versions of swift

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `override` should work.